# container keep exiting right after running it

Tags: docker, docker-compose

docker-compose.yaml:

```
web:
  build: .
  command: ./main
  ports:
   - "8888:3412"
  volumes:
   - .:/code
  links:
   - redis
redis:
  image: redis
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.6
ADD main.go .
EXPOSE 3412
ENTRYPOINT /go
RUN go build main.go
```

so after running `docker run -d imagename`, there is no running container

also `docker logs containername` doesn't show anything

Comment: Could you include the rest of the code as well? The Go code, and how you build `imagename`?

Comment: @HaraldNordgren the code worked fine (tried `docker run -it` and ran main manually which worked). it would log error if it couldnt build right ?

Comment: I didn't say there was anything wrong the rest of the code. But it helps us reproduce your exact problem to potentially help you fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ENTRYPOINT /go
```

is equivalent to running `/bin/sh -c /go`

`go` is actually a directory in your container, so it will fail, because shell cannot execute a directory.

remove the background flag `-d` and use `docker run imagename` and you will see this error

What you probably want is:
`ENTRYPOINT /usr/local/go/bin/go` to use go as an executable from the container.

Or even better:

`ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/go/bin/go"]`, so you would be able to pass arguments to go.

Comment: removed entrypoint and changed command to `/go/main`, doesnt work and doesnt  show any error

Comment: include the output of:
`docker ps -n 1 --no-trunc`

Comment: `Exited (0) 12 minutes ago`

Comment: please include the whole output

Comment: id:416f37a4af2150a3302dad7fcb1f8565d916eb55ce57d7113ea23099f2ef071c, k8s-temp_web:"/bin/bash", created:12 minutes ago, status:(0) 12 minutes ago, name:thirsty_northcutt